# Is it possible have a default signature on documents when sending an Envelope using Docusign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to pre-attach my signature to a document, before sending it to the recipients. Can it be done using docusign API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sign the documents before others do. Use the `routingorder` attribute in the signer object in your API call.

Comment: Besides the routing order, is there any way to add a default signature in all the envelopes I send ?

Comment: Do you want a signature (a "default signature") to be automatically applied by your API program? That's not possible with the DocuSign Cloud product (real people must sign). It can be done with the [DocuSign Signature Appliance](https://www.docusign.com/products/hybrid-cloud-appliances)

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to know. Thank you so much for your response.